# Class App/Models/Barang not found on Laravel 9.3

Tags: php, laravel

**I got this error** Class "app/Models/Barang" not found

this my source

```
@foreach($pesanan_details as $pesanan_detail)
      <tr>
         <td class="pt-3 pb-3">{{ $no++ }}</td>
         <td class="pt-3 pb-3">{{ $pesanan_detail->barang->nama_barang }}</td>
         <td class="pt-3 pb-3">{{ $pesanan_detail->jumlah }} </td>
      </tr>
   @endforeach
```

PesananDetail :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PesananDetail extends Model
{
    public function barang()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('app/Models/Barang','barang_id','id');
    }
    public function pesanan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('app/Models/Pesanan','pesanan_id','id');
    }
}
```

Models/Barang :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Barang extends Model
{
    public function pesanan_detail()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('app/Models/PesananDetail','barang_id','id');
    }
}
```

Im new at laravel, I don't know where the error is, pls help me

Comment: Replace the `/` with a \ in your relationship methods; it's supposed to target the namespace, not the directory.

Comment: In relationship just mention $this->belongsTo(Barang::class,'barang_id','id'); .I mean instead of mentioning path use classname Barang::class

Comment: @Daedalus it's still dont work

Comment: @JohnLobo OHHH work fine! thanks mate

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the class is `'App\Models\Barang'` not `'app/Models/Barang'`

Comment: @lagbox tried this, still error, Class "App/Models/Barang" not found

Comment: @lagbox Capital App, obviously not everywhere. since its still referencing it. also do `composer du` also you can replace `$this->hasMany(App\Models\PesananDetail::class,'barang_id','id');`

Comment: because its `App\Models\Barang` not `App/Models/Barang`

Comment: @lagbox Ohh thanks! its working now

Answer (score 0):

`App\Models\Barang` is in the namespace `App\Models`. You don't need to use the full class path

```php
namespace App\Models; // current namespace

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PesananDetail extends Model
{
    public function barang()
    {
        // refers to App\Models\Barang
        return $this->belongsTo(Barang::class, 'barang_id', 'id');
    }
}
```